# Type error: Property 'currentTime' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & HTMLInputElement'

Tags: typescript, next.js, flowplayer

I am currently using TypeScript in a nextJS project.
I am using a cdn version of flowplayer asynchronously, and it extends the event.target with new attributes.

The problem is when I try to build I get the error:
Type error: Property 'currentTime' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & HTMLInputElement'.

I need to intersect it with these attributes:  currentTime, duration, opts.
This is what I tried doing:

```
type FlowPlayerEvent<T extends EventTarget> = Event & {
target: T;
currentTime: Number;
duration: Number;
opts: Object;
};
```

This is my event handler

```
function stateHandler(ev : Event) {
const Event: FlowPlayerEvent = ev.target;
if (ev.type === 'pause') { console.log('paused'); }
if (ev.type === 'playing') { console.log(`Playing at ${Event.currentTime}, duration is: ${Event.duration}, video ID is: ${Event.opts.metadata.id}`); }
if (ev.type === 'timeupdate') { console.log(Event.currentTime); }
if (ev.type === 'ended') { console.log('The end'); }
```

}

When I hover over FlowPlayerEvent this is what I get:
Generic type 'FlowPlayerEvent' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)

What's the correct way to extend it in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `const Event: FlowPlayerEvent = ev.target;` You seem confused about what is the event and what is the target.  I'm not familiar with flowplayer.  Does it have typescript types?  Is the target supposed to be an `HTMLVideoElement` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting confused between the *event* and the *event target*.  The `currentTime` and `duration` properties exist on the target element, not the event.  These are both properties of the native `HTMLVideoElement`.  `opts` seems to be added by flowplayer so that's harder tp type.

I'm not familiar with flowplayer so I am having to look at [the docs](https://flowplayer.com/developers/player/player-api).  I'm not sure if typescript types already exist for this package.  For just the properties that you are using right here, this should work:

```
type FlowPlayerElement = HTMLVideoElement & {
    opts: {
        metadata: {
            id: string;
        }
    }
}

type FlowPlayerEvent = Event & {
    target: FlowPlayerElement;
};
```

```
function stateHandler(ev: FlowPlayerEvent) {
    const target = ev.target;
    if (ev.type === 'pause') { console.log('pausado'); }
    if (ev.type === 'playing') { console.log(`Tocando em ${target.currentTime} e a duração é: ${target.duration} e o id do vídeo: ${target.opts.metadata.id}`); }
    if (ev.type === 'timeupdate') { console.log(target.currentTime); }
    if (ev.type === 'ended') { console.log('Fim'); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What's the correct way to extend it in this case?

```
const Event: FlowPlayerEvent<MyType> = ev.target;
```

So you have to pass in a type argument.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
function stateHandler(ev: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLVideoElement>) {
    const target = ev.target;
    if (ev.type === 'pause') { console.log('pausado'); }
    if (ev.type === 'playing') { console.log(`Tocando em ${target.currentTime} e a duração é: ${target.duration} e o id do vídeo: ${target.opts.metadata.id}`); }
    if (ev.type === 'timeupdate') { console.log(target.currentTime); }
    if (ev.type === 'ended') { console.log('Fim'); }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).